# For loop weird output

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

So, I'm trying to create a javascript event that outputs puts each line of a list in an array after it is clicked. I came up with this code:

```
var lista = [];
$("#lista li").click(function(){
  for (i = 0; i < $("#lista li").length; i++) {
    if($("#lista li input")[i].checked) {
      lista.push($('#lista li')[i].innerText);
      console.log(lista);
    } else {
      lista.splice(lista.indexOf($('#lista li')[i].innerText), 1)
    }
  }
})
```

But it outputs duplicate values for the array
 What is wrong with it?

Edit:

```
<ul id="lista" class="drilldown" style="width: 100%">
                <li><input id="hemograma" type="checkbox" value="hemograma" style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><label for="hemograma" id="e0">Hemograma</label></li>
                <li><input id="glicemia" type="checkbox" value="glicemia" style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><label for="glicemia" id="e1">Glicemia de jejum</label></li>
                <li><input id="ctotal" type="checkbox" value="colesterol" style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><label for="ctotal" id="e2">Colesterol total</label></li>
                <li><input id="hdl" type="checkbox" style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><label for="hdl" id="e3">HDL</label></li>
                <li><input id="trig" type="checkbox" style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><label for="trig" id="e4">Triglicérides</label></li>
                <li><input id="TSH" type="checkbox" style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><label for="TSH" id="e5">TSH</label></li>
              </ul>
```

Comment: Any chance you can post the HTML?

Comment: no, each output is a separate "state" of the array in each iteration of the loop, there's nothing duplicated at all

Comment: @Pineda Added HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have access to JQuery core, why not use that?
https://jsfiddle.net/googabeast/udazr5vp/

```
<ul id="lista" class="drilldown" style="width: 100%">
  <li><input id="hemograma" type="checkbox" value="hemograma" style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><label for="hemograma" id="e0">Hemograma</label></li>
  <li><input id="glicemia" type="checkbox" value="glicemia" style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><label for="glicemia" id="e1">Glicemia de jejum</label></li>
  <li><input id="ctotal" type="checkbox" value="colesterol" style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><label for="ctotal" id="e2">Colesterol total</label></li>
  <li><input id="hdl" type="checkbox" style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><label for="hdl" id="e3">HDL</label></li>
  <li><input id="trig" type="checkbox" style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><label for="trig" id="e4">Triglicérides</label></li>
  <li><input id="TSH" type="checkbox" style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><label for="TSH" id="e5">TSH</label></li>
</ul> 

<div class="result"></div>




var lista = [];
$("#lista li input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
    var text = $(this).parent().text().trim();

    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        lista.push(text)
    }else{
        lista.splice(lista.indexOf(text), 1)
    };

    $(".result").text(lista.toString())
});
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I even inserted the console.log() line to double check haha. Thanks a lot, friend!

Answer (score 0):

```
var lista = [];
$("#lista li").click(function(){
    for (i = 0; i < $("#lista li").length; i++) {
        if($("#lista li input")[i].checked) {
            lista.push($('#lista li')[i].innerText);
        } else {
            lista.splice(lista.indexOf($('#lista li')[i].innerText), 1)
        }
    }
    console.log(lista);
})
```

This would output all the elements once they're added to the specified array.

**Note**: Mind that the `console.log` is outside the loop

EDIT: put the log function inside click event.

Comment: This didn't fix it. It outputs nothing at all :/

Comment: @LeonardoCanela I have edited my answer to log values on click event.

Comment: I tried it before you posted, indeed. It did not work :/
I can't post pictures, but the console logs show as if the "lista" variable is empty, even with multiple checkbox checked, and, after 6 checkbox are checked, it updates the value.